# Activate Theme Function In Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

What is the activate theme function in Wordpress? I have found switch_theme but not sure if that is the right function. Is there an activate_theme function that can be used in plugins and for development?

Answer (score 2):

[switch_theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme) does the same.